# Calculate average based on condition in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have data like this

```
Month   Value
Jan-18   3235
Feb-18   4155
.        .
.        .
.        .
Dec-18   3662
Jan-19   6623
Feb-19   3263
.        .
.        .
.        .
Dec-19   6548
Jan-20   -
Feb-20   -
March-20 -
```

[sample data view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSKQ3.png)

What I'd like to do is that from Jan-20 onwards(basically for months greater than today)I want to calculate the average for all the same months in the past years.

For example: for Jan-20, the calc should be Jan-19+Jan-18+Jan-17 and so on / n (no of months considered) to get the average.

Also, I'd like to adjust that calculated average by a parameter ranging from 1-100% uplift.

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a tableau file you can share?

Comment: Hey Jonathan, Here's the file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FUTkhB3wWX5painUxn8sANJS1xBXT5Ov/view?usp=sharing

Comment: need permission. do a tableau file with dummy numbers

Comment: Hope this would help !!

http://www.filedropper.com/book1_5

Comment: Read about table calcs in the help, especially Window_Avg() and Running_Avg()

Comment: As far as I know you cannot change data in tableau